# html.actionlink in jqgrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, jqgrid

i am trying to get a column with an html.actionlink into a jqgrid? any ideas ?
any other grid suggestions welcome too. ta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try telerik extensions for asp.net mvc. i used it personally and found it really good.
here is [link](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc) to demo page. its open source

Answer (score 1):

don't need to use telerik for column with an html.actionlink. We can use this in jqGrid itself
. Below are the code.

```
 { name: 'Restart',
                             formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                                 var x = '@Html.ActionLink( "Restart", "Restart","Dashboard",new { requestId ="myId"  }, new {@style="color:Blue;font-weight:bold;", onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure to Restart?');" })';
                                 return x.replace("myId",rowObject[8]);
                             }, align: 'left', width: 100
                         }
```

or

```
{ name: 'Restart',
                                 formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                                     return '@Html.ActionLink( "Restart", "Restart","Dashboard",new { requestId ="yourId"  }, new {@style="color:Blue;font-weight:bold;", onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure to Restart?');" })';
                                 }, align: 'left', width: 100
                             }
```

Its working fine for me